# How can I view my top tags by period of time?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, profile-page

If I look at myself under the user's tab, I can see my top tags (how're they calculated, by votes?) for that period.

[image: My weekly tags: Legend-of-zelda, Doctor-who, harry-potter]

These are my top tags for this week (starting 27/8/12).

How can I view these elsewhere?

Comment: you mean for another user? for another time period?

Comment: For anyone, for any arbitrary time period.

Comment: @Gilles I might want to see it for the last 6 months for instance